# Will it return 1 if I delete one row? -- "[Returns] the number of rows affected ... To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" ..."

Tags: meaning, comprehension, terminology

From the [SQLiteDatabase documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29):

> `public int delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`
>
> `@return`
>   the number of rows affected if a `whereClause` is passed in, 0
>   otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the
>   `whereClause`.

I am writing a program, but I can not get the exact meaning of the sentence above? Could anyone help me?

In my opinion, the method will return an `int` value that tell you how many rows you delete. But it says if you delete all rows, the delete method will return 1. But what if we delete just one row, will it still return 1?

Comment: Can we see the source from which you've given the excerpt?  The role or position (or use) of '*whereClause*' is unclear from your question.

Comment: Is there a specific word or phrase that is confusing you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Nick Moore's answer explains the meaning correctly. Now that you've clarified your confusions, I'd like to point out some important points, based on your misunderstandings:

- If your `whereClause` causes the function to delete ***one*** row, it will return 1.
- If you delete ***all*** rows (by passing `"1"` to `whereClause`), it will return the number of ***all*** rows that were deleted.
- What if you do that (deleting all rows by passing `"1"` to `whereClause`), and the table has only ***one*** row (which means, it will delete just 1 row in total), will it still return 1? ***Yes, it will return 1.*** (Given that it works as stated.)

---

#### Reading comprehension:

Let's have a closer look at the sentences.

> `@return`
>   the number of rows affected if a `whereClause` is passed in, 0 otherwise.

You can read `@return` in Javadoc documents (I presume) as "This method returns"; so it's "the method `delete()` returns ..." in our example.

It returns what? The sentence states the conditions in the pattern [ X if A-condition, Y otherwise ]. In other words, if A-condition applies, it returns X; otherwise, it returns Y.

So, this sentence means: ***If a `whereClause` is passed in, `delete()` returns the number of rows affected; otherwise (i.e. you do not specify a proper `whereClause`), it returns 0.***

> To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the `whereClause`.

I think the sentence would be clearer with a comma:
*To remove all rows and get a count, pass "1" as the `whereClause`.*

In other words,

> To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the `whereClause`.
>   (*= Pass "1" as the `whereClause` to remove all rows and get a count.*)

This **does not** say what you understand ("if you delete all rows, the delete method will return 1"). It says, "To remove all rows, pass a string `"1"` as your `whereClause`". For example, this will remove all rows: `delete(myTable, "1", myWhereArgs);`

By doing so (deleting all rows by passing `"1"` as the `whereClause`), you will get "a count" as the return value. That is, `delete()` will delete all rows, and then return the count of all deleted rows.

So, what if we delete just one row, will it still return 1? ***Yes, it will return 1.***

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I can help.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming this annotates a method definition that deletes rows from a database.

If you pass a 'whereClause' into the method, the method will return the number of rows that are deleted by the method.

If you do not pass it a 'whereClause', the method will return 0 (and presumably will delete no rows).

If you pass in a 'whereClause' with value "1", the method will remove all rows and return the number of rows deleted.

Comment: I've edited the question..